# Vue foreach not filtering correctly

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuejs2

I've been trying Vue 1.x and I've just recently switched over to 2.x and I've been slowly modifying some stuff, mainly directives.

Right now I'm struggling with a filtering of an array. Imagine that I have 3 items, A, B and C. No matter which one I say is being filtered out, it's always the last element that appears. So imagine I delete A, then C will dissapear.

I've created a jsFiddle as an example: https://jsfiddle.net/arj70sz4/

As required by StackOverflow:

for-each code from HTML:

```
<foo-single
  v-for="foo in foos"
  v-bind:foo="foo"
>
</foo-single>
```

filtering code from JS:

```
this.foos = this.foos.filter(function (v) {
  return foo.id != v.id;
});
```

I know there is another way to do this filtering, by splicing the array, but that way the same result was occurring.

Could someone enlighten me? I feel as if my mistake is actually pretty dumb but I can't seem to figure it out right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to add [key](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#key) in [v-for](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#v-for)

```
<foo-single v-for="foo in foos" v-bind:foo="foo" :key="foo.id">
</foo-single>
```

For the improvement of performance, v-for uses an “in-place patch” strategy and list rendering will not change on child component state or temporary DOM state changes. To track these changes you need to add key attribute with v-for.

See working fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/mimani/arj70sz4/1/).

Comment: Thank you so much, it works. Hadn't read on the :key attribute which was right below the example I had also tried: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Components-and-v-for